# The local var does not override the parameter of the same name?

Tags: javascript

This just blew my mind:

```js
function f(x) {
    var x;
    console.log(x); // prints 100!
}

f(100);
```

I always used to think that whenever you declare the local variable, anything with the same name that was declared before becomes hidden behind it. Why `var x` does not make `x` `undefined` as it used to do in other situations?

Compare with this code, which behaves as I used to:

```js
var x = 100;
function f() {
    var x;
    console.log(x); // prints undefined as expected
}

f();
```

Comment: The `var` declaration is basically ignored because the symbol is already declared.

Comment: The second code example is not relevant because two different scopes are involved. The formal parameter list in the function declaration effectively does the same thing as `var` declarations for the parameter symbols in the lexical scope of the function.

Comment: `The local var` -- This phrase makes me think you misunderstand what local variables really are. Function arguments are also local variables. So basically what you have done is this: `var x = 100; var x` which is legal in javascript to allow people to do declare `var` in for loops etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For function code, parameters are also added as bindings to that Environment Record.**

The defined parameter `x` is scooped to the current function. Since `x` is already been declared in the function, as a parameter, the `var x`; declaration will be ignored.

For more details: http://es5.github.io/#x10.5

Answer (score 2):

Both `var` and the parameter declare the same variable `x` in the same function scope. When the variable is created, it is initialised to `undefined`, and shortly after assigned the value `100` that was passed as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

From [**MDN#var**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> **Description**
>
> ...If you re-declare a JavaScript variable, it will not lose its value.

In the first example, since `x` is already declared within the function `f` (as an argument), redeclaring it (using `var`) inside the same function will keep the same value for `x` before that redeclaration (which is the parameter given to `f` when it is called).

In the second example, `x` is declared within the function `f`. So when looking up `x`'s value to pass on to `log` we use that `x` inside `f` (not the outside one), and since we didn't explicitly give it a value (initializing it), its value is going to be `undefined`.